# In Visual Studio 2010 Professional edition where is the profiler tool to analyze bottlenecks?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, profiler

I was playing around with the buttons and menus in VS10 Professional edition and up popped up a dialog box asking if I wanted to profile my code, presumably to discover bottlenecks. I closed the dialog but now I want to find this feature again and cannot (I guess I am not much of a professional huh?)

Can anybody tell me where this feature, under what menu, it exists?  I don't like using command line switches so please just in the GUI if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Professional doesn't include profiling, you will need Preminum or Ultimate edition for that. CHeck this [VS edition comparison page](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/product-comparison).

Comment: Fine... but is there any 3rd party profiler plugin for VS Professional?